# How to get the Android Emulator's IP address?

Tags: android, ip, android-virtual-device

I want to get the currently running [Android Emulator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29#Software_development_kit)'s IP address through code.
How can it be achieved?

Comment: Perhaps related [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447221/how-to-connect-to-avd) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217796/is-android-avds-firewall-somehow-more-restricted-to-real-android-firewall).

Comment: @hhh Second link is broken. :)

Comment: @MuhamedHuseinbašić I feel this thread solved the problem in the second thread so decided to delete it to keep things simple.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Just to clarify: from within your app, you can simply refer to the Emulator as "`localhost`" or `127.0.0.1`.

Web traffic is routed through your development machine, so the Emulator's **External-IP** is whatever External-IP has been assigned to that development machine by your internet-provider. The development machine can always be reached from your device at `10.0.2.2`.

If you have multiple Emulators launched, where `adb` does not work,
unless you [pick one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14655015/8740349) by Emulator's Local-IP (like `adb -s 192.168.232.2:5555 shell`), then:

- Just like a real Android device,
- In Emulator, swipe down from top-most, to open menu,
- In the menu, press and hold on WiFi,
- Finally, go to settings of current WiFi-connection,
- There you should see IP of Emulator process.

Comment: I want to upvote you 100 times for this. I couldn't figure out how my app could talk to another local server I had running until I read your post. Thanks!

Comment: How can you reach your development machine from 10.0.2.2? I tried pinging but nothing, pic [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Yjv7W.jpg). Ifconfig -app on the right and terminal-emulator on the left trying to ping dev-machine. Cannot see anything in localhost, any simple tests?

Comment: @hhh You can try JuiceSSH: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonelli.juicessh You can reach your host from the mentioned IP or from the real IP of the host. Both variants work for me.

Comment: I believe the traffic from an emulator is routed over a "virtual" router first (with IP address of `10.0.2.1`, not directly. So, there should be one extra connection takes place between this router `10.0.2.1` to the host/dev machine `127.0.0.1/10.0.2.2`. What I really usually change the port number I want to connect to.

Answer (score 43):

If you do truly want the IP assigned to your emulator:

```
adb shell
ifconfig eth0
```

> Which may give you something like:
>
> ```
> eth0: ip 10.0.2.15 mask 255.255.255.0 flags [up broadcast running multicast]
> ```

Or, if above fails, try:

```
adb shell
ifconfig wlan0
```

> And look for `inet addr:` in the output,
> for example, my Emulator logs `inet addr:192.168.232.2`

Comment: [Luise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6066443/louise) said: *I tried Derek method. it can ping within adb shell*.

Comment: I get this error after `adb shell`: `ifconfig: eth0: No such device`any ideas why?

Comment: @awavi it might be under a different interface like `wlan0`

Answer (score 27):

Like this:

```
public String getLocalIpAddress() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Check the docs for more info: [NetworkInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/NetworkInterface.html).

Comment: And don't forget 'the android.permission.INTERNET' permission

Comment: This gives IP6 address, how to get IP4?

Answer (score 21):

**Use this method you will be getting 100% correct ip address for your android emulator**

To get the ip address of yoor emulator

Go to adb shell and type this command

```
adb shell
ifconfig eth0
```

[image]

After running this command I am getting

**IP : 10.0.2.15**

**Mask : 255.255.255.0**

Which works for me . I am also working for an networking application.

Comment: The emulator no longer has 'eth0', but has 'radio0' and 'wlan0' instead.  You may want to edit this answer, because it is no longer 100% correct.

Comment: I'm on macOS. `ifconfig: en0: No such device`.

Answer (score 12):

If you need to refer to your host computer's localhost, such as when you want the emulator client to contact a server running on the host, use the alias **10.0.2.2** to refer to the host computer's loopback interface. From the emulator's perspective, **localhost (127.0.0.1)** refers to its own loopback interface.

More details: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#networkaddresses

Comment: This answer worked for me. Remember to include the computer's port: `http://10.0.2.2:3000/api`, for example, for a web api.

Answer (score 3):

```
public String getLocalIpAddress() {

    try {
        for (Enumeration < NetworkInterface > en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration < InetAddress > enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the code of my app I can get the running device IP andress easily like beolow:

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally the IP address of the android emulator is `10.0.0.2` you check it from the Wi-Fi setting in the emulator