# Reaching a network device by IP and port using the Android emulator

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, client, host

Why does my Java app for Android not connect to the server?

I run the application in Android emulator, and the server which is on port 9999 and host 127.0.0.1 in my pc, but it will just not connect and I think this method isn't good for Sndroid app.

**Update: I work with API 8 and Android 2.2**

This is my source code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
//Java imports
//import android.util.Log;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class MainActivity extends Activity{
//Variaveis Interface
private Button ligar;
private Button enviar;
private EditText text1;
private TextView text2;
//Variaveis
static Socket cSocket;
static PrintWriter out;
static BufferedReader in;
   

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    
    //Declaração butões
    ligar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ligar);
    enviar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enviar);
    text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);

    //Interacao
    ligar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0){
             connect();
        }
    });
    enviar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0){
               out.println("Hello");
               text2.setText("");
        }
    });
  }
  //Outras Funcoes

public void connect(){
//Funcao ligar
cSocket = null;
out = null;
in = null;

try{
   cSocket = new Socket("10.0.2.2",4444);
   out = new PrintWriter(cSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
   in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cSocket.getInputStream()));
   text2.setText("Estas conectado com sucesso.");
   }
   catch (IOException ex) {
   //Logger.getLogger(client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   text2.setText("Erro! Na conexão");
   }                
   }
//
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted, or post your own solution (in case the answers below didn't solve your problem) and accept it. Whenever you solve your problem, you should "finalize" the question marking one answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720346/how-to-get-the-android-emulators-ip-address):

Host machine can be reached using IP address `10.0.2.2` from the emulator.

**edit, answer to your comment:*

For completeness and to better understand my answer, read the [Android Emulator documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html).

These are the [IP addresses as reached from the emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html#emulatornetworking):

- `10.0.2.1`, Router/gateway address.
- `10.0.2.2`, Special alias to your ***host*** loopback interface (i.e., 127.0.0.1 on your development machine)
- `10.0.2.3`, First DNS server
- `10.0.2.4` / `10.0.2.5` / `10.0.2.6`, Optional second, third and fourth DNS server (if any)
- `10.0.2.15`, The ***emulated*** device's own ***network/ethernet interface***
- `127.0.0.1`, The ***emulated*** device's own ***loopback interface***

That said, we have:

- Common mistake 1: accessing `127.0.0.1` from the emulator trying to reach your host machine. Use `10.0.2.2`, as I said.
- Common mistake 2: Trying to access an emulator service on `HostComputerIP:appServicePort`. It won't work since your host computer itself (Windows, Linux, OS etc.) is not running a service in that port. You need to redirect a port on the emulator **console** to a port on an emulated **Android instance** itself (see 2 below).

Common networking needs:

**1- Emulator app as client and local computer as server**

Because the emulator is NAT'd, I believe you can connect to any computer on your local network directly. I mean, since the *virtual* router has access to both networks, it should be able to handle outgoing (i.e., emulator->real lan) connections just fine.

*Example:* on my network (192.168.0.x), I can connect *from* the emulator to my *real* router (`192.168.0.254`) just pointing the emulator web browser to `http://192.168.0.254:port`. I use different services on it (hail to Tomato!), and I can access all of them on each `port`. No need to handle port forwarding, *as expected*.

***By the looks of your code, I believe you need:***

```
// I assume 192.168.0.114 is your server, which is
// located on your local network, running a server application
// on port 9999.
cSocket = new Socket("192.168.0.114",9999);
```

**2- Local computer as client and emulator app as server**

Now that's a different story. You need to setup [port redirections](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html#redirection) on the *virtual* router. The easiest way is:

Telnet into the "management" system (this is not the emulator), from your **host** (your computer, console on linux or command prompt on Windows):

```
telnet localhost 5554
```

After that, use:

```
adb forward tcp:localPort tcp:emulatorPort
```

After this, you will be able to have a service on `emulatorPort` and you will be able to connect to it from computers in the local network by accessing `hostComputerIP:localPort`.

This is the way people (including me) use, for example, SSHDroid inside an emulator.

Anything else?

Comment: Yep this is correct, I pulled my hair out for a while on this issue once.

Comment: Not work... and a already test with a wirelless link, the emulador in a diferent pc that Server !

Comment: You should have told that it's in a different pc than the server. You said "host 127.0.0.1 in *my* pc", so we guessed it was the same. Anyway, I updated the answer with two solutions for your problem, depending on what *exactly* you want to do.

Comment: No, it's the same.. but i already test in different pc that emulator.. sorry my bad english.

Comment: No problem about the English. So... answer YES/NO to me: 1) your code is in the emulator, 2) your server is in the local network, 3) your server is *NOT* in the same machine as your emulator. --- Is that right?

Comment: Não entendi, então vou falar português mesmo. Antes você disse "the emulador in a diferent pc that Server", agora você disse "[server] is the same machine". Se está no mesmo computador, use 10.0.2.2. Se ainda assim você não consegue é porque tem algum problema de firewall ou alguma coisa está errado no seu computador.

Comment: Sim disse, mas disse que foi só um teste que fiz,e não funcionou... sim, eu conheço o 10.0.2.2, mas já vou testar melho. Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

127.0.0.1 goes to localhost. While that is your own computer from your PC, it's the phone from the phone. You need to provide the actual IP address. Additionally, if you haven't already set it, make sure you request the Internet permission. See the [doc on permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html) and [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378607/what-permission-do-i-need-to-access-internet-from-an-android-application).

**Update:**
To answer your comment, as David points out from the emulator you can use `10.0.2.2` to reach your host machine.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 goes to local host of android or my windows pc ! I test my app in android emulator e server in windows that run emulator.. you understand ?;)

Comment: the android emulator is a virtual machine, so the 127.0.0.1 refers to the localhost of the android emulator S.O itself.

Comment: okay.. i understand ! So how can i test? Or what Ip host i can use in android to connect server ?