# UDP port forwarding for android emulator; "adb forward udp:port udp:port" and telnet localhost adb_port not working

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, telnet

Hi I am developing an app using android emulator. I need to register a UDP socket at some port X that can be accessible from local network. Since Android emulator is NAT'd so I need port forwarding.
I followed this post "[Reaching a network device by IP and port using the Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191192/reaching-a-network-device-by-ip-and-port-using-the-android-emulator)". It shows that I need to use

```
adb forward tcp:localPort tcp:emulatorPort
```

but this scheme doesn't work for udp (If anyone knows its version for UDP then please let me know). For UDP I found another solution that I need to telnet to adb port as follows (My adb is running at port 5037)

```
telnet localhost 5037
```

and redirect UDP port using redir command

```
redir add udp:36963:36963
```

But when I telnet it gives the following error

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 5037

Connecting to 127.0.0.1:5037...
Connection established.
To escape to local shell, press 'Ctrl+Alt+]'.

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I tried a lot to find any solution for this but fruitless.

I need to know any solution for accessing emulator from outer network.

Comment: Kanwar, did you find a solution to the problem already? I'm really interested in this answer

Answer (score 3):

The typical telnet port for the first emulator is 5554.

Try:

```sh
telnet localhost 5554
```

Then you'll need to authenticate, the instructions are printed in the console. It should be something like copy the value from $HOME/.emulator_console_auth_token without the trailing '%'.

```sh
auth <auth_token>
redir add udp:36963:36963
```

Answer (score -2):

This is wrong

```
redir add udp:36963:36963
```

Try this:

```
redir add udp:portA udp:portB
```

In the most of the cases portA and portB will be different. Adapt to your code

Comment: the problem is I wont be able to telnet. after that i can run this command. That's what I have asked that how to fix this issue

Comment: windows shell have some problems with telnet. Try use PowerShell instead or other shell. If you want a graphicall enviroment you can use Putty to telnet

Comment: When I `adb shell` onto my device I get `/system/bin/sh: redir: not found` when I try to execute the `redir add` command. How can overcome that?

Comment: @CsabaToth it's only available through the telnet connection not shell.