# Telnet Sip Server From Android Emulator Jain Sip Application

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, android-debug

I have successfully implement the jain-sip application on android and I have Sip-Servlet application deployed on mobicent-server.

I have mobicent-jbossas7 server running on port `127.0.0.1:5080` (Sip-UDP).

I have created SipStack on port `5060` and

I have Outbound proxy set to `10.0.2.2:5070`

My problem is packets are not sending to mobicent-server from android emulator. I have implement `redir` command like this

```
`>telnet localhost 5554`
`>redir add udp:5070:5080 OK`
```

I get following wireshark captured packets giving me `ICMP Port Unreachable Error Message`

[image: Following output which Showing ICMP Error Message, How to troubleshoot this?]

**Additional:** I have tried `redir add udp:5080:5070` I received following output
[image]

How I setup application to connect to server for sending request and receiving response from sip-servlet? Please Help me

Comment: May be the port is not redirecting to 5080 port of development machine? May be because emulator has its own loopback interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have done sending request to sip server and getting back response to android emulator
[image]

I have set the OUTBOUND_PROXY of Sip Stack to `10.0.2.2` with port of `5080`. This is the localhost and the port of my server running in development machine. 
Getting Idea from [this link](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking) and also learning from reading [David Cesarino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191192/reaching-a-network-device-by-ip-and-port-using-the-android-emulator) answer.

I also used `telnet`  to redir from port 5080 (Server service port) to 5060 (Listening point) since emulator is acting as a type of server. As per reading from [David Cesarino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191192/reaching-a-network-device-by-ip-and-port-using-the-android-emulator) answer.