# Accessing node.js server on my local system using android app

Tags: android, node.js

I have a **node.js** server running on my local system which interacts with **postgresql** in the same system to fetch and save data. I want to access **node.js server** from my android app to save and fetch data from **postresql**. The problem is my app is not able to connect to localhost. As localhost for my phone is different from my local system and if I am providing my **system's IP address** then also its refusing the connection.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: You would simply access it using your local address, which is 127.0.0.1.  Don't forget to specify http and the port number as well, as per usual.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is for localhost which would not be the correct IP address if I am accessing it from android app in my phone.

Comment: Maybe you can replace `127.0.0.1` to `*`. because `*` stands for all ip address.

Comment: @BlackMamba That will not work.

Comment: Make the `Node.js` server listen on your `IP` not `localhost` nor `127.0.0.1` and from `Android` make the call to that `IP` and don't forget to make sure that `Android` device is on the same network with the `Node.js` server.

Comment: @EslamEl-Meniawy I am already using my system's IP in URL to access node.js server i.e http://198.164.1.24:3000/api/v1/object but still it is refusing connection. I am sure that my system and my phone both are on same network and I have disabled system's firewall also.

Comment: @vishalgaurav Then I guess you need to add code to your question for people to see what exactly you are doing and if there is a problem with the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made server listen to hostname '0.0.0.0'. Initially I was not providing any hostname as argument in server.listen i.e it was like
server.listen('portnumber') which I changed to
server.listen('portnumber', '0.0.0.0');

Answer (score 1):

if you are using android emulator and trying to access the the host machine's

- **local host** use IP address : 10.0.2.2
- **for genymotion** use IP address: 10.0.2.3

this should allow you to access the host machine's local host, but you will have to change this IP address to local IP address when running app on a device and connected to same network, to access from other network you need to open port(port forwarding I guess) in your router and talk ask your ISP to do the same.

here's a link to similar question : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8191192/1575353)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same kind of issues

- I wasn't able to call the API from emulator. I made it working by replacing localhost with 10.0.2.2:YOUR_PORT_NUMBER
- I was able to call from an external device using ngrok ([https://ngrok.com/](https://medium.com/@neerajmoudgil/how-to-test-localhost-node-apis-on-android-device-253fcdd32c18))
- If you want to call api without using external services go through this article may be helpful [Link](https://medium.com/@neerajmoudgil/how-to-test-localhost-node-apis-on-android-device-253fcdd32c18)