# App fails to connect to a simple server

Tags: java, android

I've made a simple chat app for desktop use in Java along with a server. Now, I rebuilt the desktop app into an android one. The only problem is I can't get it to connect to the server. It didn't work in the background so I tried with a button but still no result.

I am running the server in eclipse and the app in an android studio with an emulator.

IMPORTANT NOTE: It shows error:

```
08-01 18:00:57.255 8914-8914/com.example.android.chatnow E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.chatnow, PID: 8914
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.chatnow/com.example.android.chatnow.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1450)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:355)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:357)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:616)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:565)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:445)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:217)
        at com.example.android.chatnow.MainActivity.setUpNetworking(MainActivity.java:29)
        at com.example.android.chatnow.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.android.chatnow;
import java.io.*;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.net.*;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    BufferedReader reader;
    PrintWriter writer;
    Socket sock;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Thread readerThread = new Thread(new IncomingReader());
        readerThread.start();
    }
    public void onSendMessage(View view) {
        EditText messageView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.message);
        String messageText = messageView.getText().toString();
        //writer.println(": " +messageText);
        //writer.flush();
    }
    public void setUpNetworking(View view) {
        try {
            sock=new Socket("10.0.2.2", 5000);
            InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
            reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
            writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
            Log.d("NiceTag", "Net established");
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("NiceTag", "Net failed");
        }
    }
    public class IncomingReader implements Runnable{
        public void run() {
            String message;
            try {
                while ( (message=reader.readLine())!=null) {
                    TextView messageView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.displaymessage);
                    messageView.append( message + '\n');
                }
                System.out.println("!while");
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/displaymessage"
        android:layout_width="262dp"
        android:layout_height="401dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/displaymessage" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="Send"
        android:onClick="onSendMessage"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.469"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/message"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/displaymessage" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Connect"
        android:onClick="setUpNetworking"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/displaymessage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also, the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.chatnow">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

P.S. Server and emulator are running on the same device

Comment: use Socket.io library.

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya what's the problem with using java.net?

Comment: Use the actual external IP of the host. Also make sure that Socket is not only listening locally on the server

Comment: @cricket_007 how can i see if socket is only listening locally?

Comment: It appears you are receiving a NetworkOnMainThreadException. You need to move the code that connects to your server to a separate thread off the main thread. For example you can use an AsyncTask.

Comment: To avoid UI freeze Android doesn't permit network on the main thread, you need to move the code and wait for callbacks into separated threads such: Thread + Runnable + Handler, AsyncTask or  IntentService.

Comment: Yes indeed, it works now. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I executed your code and I ended up with the following exception:

**android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException**
which means that you have to migrate your code from your main thread to a worker or background thread.

One way to do that is to introduce an `AsyncTask` as the following:

```
private class ConnectSimpleServerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private Socket sock;

    private ConnectSimpleServerTask(Socket sock) {
        this.sock = sock;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            sock=new Socket("10.0.2.2", 5000);
            InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
            reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
            writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
            Log.d("NiceTag", "Net established");
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("NiceTag", "Net failed");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and in your `setUpNetworking`, do this:

```
public void setUpNetworking(View view) {
        new ConnectSimpleServerTask(sock).execute();
    }
```

This is just a starting point, you can modify your `AsyncTask` as you please. Then, after executing with the current worker Thread,

*the socket obj is still being null which means that is an issue with host or the port.*

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8191487/5544859) that might help you on setting up the right host and port, take a look at it.

Comment: haha I just figured it out by myself 2 minutes ago :) . Thanks very much for answer ! Also, i printed the exception in a wrong way. I should have used IOException instead.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. I modified Exception to IOException. After thet, I created a Thread for setUpNetworking! Thanks all for your answers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you have your Android app running in the Emulator on your local machine and server running on the same machine, then `localhost` won't refer to your server application. If you want to refer to the server application, then you should call the following IP address: `10.0.2.2` from the emulator running on the same machine as server.

When you call the server from the physical device, then find your IP address via `ifconfig` command (or `ipconfig` on Windows) in terminal, connect the mobile device to the same local network as server via WiFi and use appropriate IP address in your Android app.

**EDIT**

After your last edit, problem is more clear.
You have two issues:

- setting the wrong host - it should be `10.0.2.2` instead of
  `localhost`
- calling request in the main thread - request should be called in a separate thread - e.g. with the [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) (see official docs to find out how to use this class)

Comment: Nope, already tried that both on a physical device and on emulator.

Comment: Check out my last edit, I found errors

Comment: I've updated my answer a moment ago.

Comment: Yes it was because of AsyncTask. Also , thanks for the 10.0.2.2 thing