# IPC between Android app and native user space process

Tags: java, android, c++, ipc, aidl

I understand that IPC between different apps on Android has been discussed a lot, and there are quite a few articles on how to use mechanism like AIDL. But all the examples I came across are different from my case here:

- The online examples of IPC I found are regarding two apps managed by ART (Android Run Time), even though some examples covered how to use AIDL in native C++ code, these C++ codes are called within a process **managed by ART** and have JVM involed.
- In my case, I have an Android server app managed by ART, and a C++ client executable that is **not** managed by ART and has **zero Java code**. This client executable is not an APK normally launched from the home screen, and has no JVM created when running, it is a Linux executable pushed to device via adb, and executed from the adb shell, just like what we do on Linux.

For my use case, what are the available mechanism for IPC?

(In case you are wondering why I want run a native Linux process in adb shell, here is why: with Android port available on Raspberry Pi and some other SOC devices, you can build your own Android ROM from source and re-use existing Linux code to run some apps on these devices)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unclear if you've seen: https://source.android.com/docs/core/architecture/aidl

Comment: @MorrisonChang, thanks for the link. The doc seems under platform development, which is new to me. I think the AIDL materials I came across in the past are targeting app developers. For my case, what I need to do with my C++ native executable to connect to the service provided by an APK? I was under the assumption that my C++ code can just call some Android libs to do so, but it might be more complex than I thought. If there are some examples, that would be greatly helpful, thanks again!

Comment: Any IPC that exists directly on Linux ought to work-  there's a linux layer at some point and worst case you can use JNI to call it in C.

Comment: Realize that you may be trying to do this: [Android app talking to Android native binary via sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10910768/295004)

Comment: @GabeSechan, does using JNI in C require creaing JVM instance by JNI_CreateJavaVM(), if my native executable is running as a native process?

Comment: @MorrisonChang, I was also thinking about Unix domain socket and/or shared memory. I did this on Linux in the past, but not sure if Android adds some restrictions on it, will try it anyway. Thanks!

Comment: @DarkSoda No, that's how you go from C to Java if you r app starts as C.  Inside a Java app, you just need to mark a function as native, include the C library, and match the function names properly.  https://www.baeldung.com/jni has the basics, or you can google for other tutorials.  You may not need to go this far, but worst case it will work