# How to get the IP address of an emulator to communicate to the local server

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the Android Emulator's IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720346/how-to-get-the-android-emulators-ip-address)

Can anyone give me some idea about getting the IP address of the emulator to connect to the local server to retrieve the contents of a particular application which is currently running using that emulator..

Comment: the answer is out there, this question has been asked before.

Answer (score 1):

to connect to the local server your can simply address it by `10.0.2.2`

Answer (score 0):

It is usally the IP of the PC running the emulator. The network connection is shared. You need to ensure that the firewall on your PC does not filter out this connections.