# How to use ADB Shell when Multiple Devices are connected? Fails with "error: more than one device and emulator"

Tags: android, shell, cmd, adb, android-debug

```
$ adb --help
```

---

```
-s SERIAL  use device with given serial (overrides $ANDROID_SERIAL)
```

---

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
emulator-5554   device
7f1c864e    device
```

---

```
$ adb shell -s 7f1c864e
error: more than one device and emulator
```

Answer (score 1292, accepted):

Use the `-s` option BEFORE the command to specify the device, for example:

```
adb -s 7f1c864e shell
```

For multiple Emulator, use the process's IP and port as the id, like:

```
adb -s 192.168.232.2:5555 <command>
```

> See [How to get the Android Emulator's IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1720346/8740349)
>
> But if there is only a single Emulator, try:
>
> ```
> adb -e <command>
> ```

See also http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#directingcommands

Comment: For an emulator, you use the IP and port as the id, e.g.: `adb -s 192.168.56.101:5555 shell`

Comment: For an emulator use `adb -e shell` or `adb emu <command>`. They'll fail if there's more than one emulator going and you'll have to fall back to `-s`

Comment: Note you have to use the `-s` option before `shell`. It is a very bad user experience that you cannot do this the other way around...

Comment: For wireless debugging, you use the IP and port as the id, e.g.: `adb -s 192.168.178.81:45635 shell`

Comment: Note that `shell` is replaceable with whatever command you want to execute on the previously specified device. In my case the command looks like this: `adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`.

Comment: Note that -s has to be <<<BEFORE>>> the command

Comment: How we can find out ip and port for device connected with ip

Answer (score 380):

**`adb -d shell`** (or `adb -e shell`).

This command will help you in most of the cases, if you are too lazy to type the full ID.

From http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#commandsummary:

> `-d` - Direct an adb command to the only attached USB **device**. Returns an error when more than one USB device is attached.
>
> `-e` - Direct an adb command to the only running **emulator**. Returns an error when more than one emulator is running.

Comment: **Very** useful if you only have one USB device and one emulator, which I imagine is most people. Thanks!

Comment: And just a little mnemonic to help remember it each time `-d` is for **"device"** and `-e` is for **"emulator"**. And if you already figured this out, give yourself a pat on the back. ;)

Comment: This should be the TOP answer

Comment: Thank you, I just need to know how to go back to normal, or to switch between modes.

Answer (score 55):

Another alternative would be to set environment variable ANDROID_SERIAL to the relevant serial, here assuming you are using Windows:

```
set ANDROID_SERIAL=7f1c864e
echo %ANDROID_SERIAL%
"7f1c864e"
```

Then you can use `adb.exe shell` without any issues.

Comment: Should be `set ANDROID_SERIAL=7f1c864e`, ie. without quotes.

Comment: For bash, it should be `export ANDROID_SERIAL=7f1c864e`.

Comment: For powershell, it should be `$env:ANDROID_SERIAL="7f1c864e"`

Answer (score 49):

***To install an apk on one of your emulators:***

First get the list of devices:

```
-> adb devices
List of devices attached
25sdfsfb3801745eg        device
emulator-0954   device
```

Then install the apk on your emulator with the `-s` flag:

```
-> adb -s "25sdfsfb3801745eg" install "C:\Users\joel.joel\Downloads\release.apk"
Performing Streamed Install
Success
```

Ps.: the order here matters, so `-s <id>` has to come before `install` command, otherwise it won't work.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 47):

I found this question after seeing the 'more than one device' error, with 2 offline phones showing:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\android-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
SH436WM01785    offline
SH436WM01785    offline
SH436WM01785    sideload
```

If you only have one device connected, run the following commands to get rid of the offline connections:

```
adb kill-server
adb devices
```

Comment: `adb kill-server` fixes the problem with offline emulators

Comment: adb kill-server also helped to get rid of several emulator-nnnn devices which were haunting my sdk (because it was pulled as a copy from Android Studio)

Comment: adb kill-server killed my online one and my offline one was not removed

Comment: adb kill-server sorted all the problems

Answer (score 16):

The best way to run shell on any particular device is to use:

```
adb -s << emulator UDID >> shell

For Example:
adb -s emulator-5554 shell
```

Answer (score 11):

As per https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#directingcommands

What worked for my testing:

UBUNTU BASH TERMINAL:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
646269f0    device
8a928c2 device
$ export ANDROID_SERIAL=646269f0
$ echo $ANDROID_SERIAL
646269f0
$ adb reboot bootloader
```

WINDOWS COMMAND PROMPT:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
646269f0    device
8a928c2 device
$ set ANDROID_SERIAL=646269f0
$ echo $ANDROID_SERIAL$
646269f0
$ adb reboot bootloader
```

This enables you to use normal commands and scripts as if there was only the ANDROID_SERIAL device attached.

Alternatively, you can mention the device serial every time.

```
$ adb -s 646269f0 shell
```

Answer (score 7):

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/dtmilano/4537110) will do most of the work for you showing a menu when there are multiple devices connected:

```
$ adb $(android-select-device) shell
1) 02783201431feeee device 3) emulator-5554
2) 3832380FA5F30000 device 4) emulator-5556
Select the device to use, <Q> to quit:
```

To avoid typing you can just create an alias that included the device selection as explained [here](http://dtmilano.blogspot.ca/2012/03/selecting-adb-device.html).

Comment: Looks nice. Too bad it is incompatible with Windows (including Cygwin).

Comment: The only device ID which is always unique is the USB port of connection (e.g. "usb:3-4"). Other IDs should not be used for identification, as they could be identical for different devices. Here I propose a fork of your nice script, which uses only USB id for -s specification: https://gist.github.com/dmikushin/4495487dffd01af17c132644b8592cdd

Comment: @DmitryMikushin thanks for the improvement!

Answer (score 6):

User `@janot` has already mentioned this above, but this took me some time to filter the best solution.

There are two Broad use cases:
1) 2 hardware are connected, first is emulator and other is a Device.
**Solution** : `adb -e shell....whatever-command` for emulator and `adb -d shell....whatever-command` for device.

2) n number of devices are connected (all emulators or Phones/Tablets) via USB/ADB-WiFi:
**Solution**: 
Step1) run `adb devices` THis will give you list of devices currently connected (via USB or ADBoverWiFI)
Step2) now run `adb -s <device-id/IP-address> shell....whatever-command`
no matter how many devices you have.

**Example**
 to clear app data on a device connected on wifi ADB I would execute:
`adb -s 172.16.34.89:5555 shell pm clear com.package-id`

to clear app data connected on my usb connected device I would execute:
`adb -s 5210d21be2a5643d shell pm clear com.package-id`

Answer (score 5):

For Windows, here's a quick 1 liner example of how to install a file..on multiple devices

```
FOR /F "skip=1"  %x IN ('adb devices') DO start adb -s %x install -r myandroidapp.apk
```

If you plan on including this in a batch file, replace %x with %%x, as below

```
FOR /F "skip=1"  %%x IN ('adb devices') DO start adb -s %%x install -r myandroidapp.apk
```

Comment: I recommend replacing `install -r .... ` with `%1` and then saving this script somewhere in your path. That way you can directly invoke any adb command you like by calling the script with a parameter. For example, if you call you script `adball` then you can call `adball uninstall myapp`

Answer (score 4):

Create a Bash (tools.sh) to select a serial from devices (or emulator):

```
clear;
echo "====================================================================================================";
echo " ADB DEVICES";
echo "====================================================================================================";
echo "";

adb_devices=( $(adb devices | grep -v devices | grep device | cut -f 1)#$(adb devices | grep -v devices | grep device | cut -f 2) );

if [ $((${#adb_devices[@]})) -eq "1" ] && [ "${adb_devices[0]}" == "#" ]
then
    echo "No device found";
    echo ""; 
    echo "====================================================================================================";
    device=""
    // Call Main Menu function fxMenu;
else
    read -p "$(
        f=0
        for dev in "${adb_devices[@]}"; do
            nm="$(echo ${dev} | cut -f1 -d#)";
            tp="$(echo ${dev} | cut -f2 -d#)";
            echo " $((++f)). ${nm} [${tp}]";
        done

        echo "";
        echo " 0. Quit"
        echo "";

        echo "====================================================================================================";
        echo "";
        echo ' Please select a device: '
    )" selection

    error="You think it's over just because I am dead. It's not over. The games have just begun.";
    // Call Validation Numbers fxValidationNumberMenu ${#adb_devices[@]} ${selection} "${error}" 
    case "${selection}" in
        0)
            // Call Main Menu function fxMenu;
        *)  
            device="$(echo ${adb_devices[$((selection-1))]} | cut -f1 -d#)";
            // Call Main Menu function fxMenu;
    esac
fi
```

Then in another option can use `adb -s` (global option -s use device with given serial number that overrides $ANDROID_SERIAL):

```
adb -s ${device} <command>
```

I tested this code on MacOS terminal, but I think it can be used on windows across Git Bash Terminal.

Also remember configure environmental variables and Android SDK paths on `.bash_profile` file:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH"
```

Comment: Using Ubuntu 16.04: 
/home/user/bin/select_device: line 35: fxValidationNumberMenu: command not found
/home/user/bin/select_device: line 41: fxMenu: command not found

Comment: @gerbit `fxMenu` and `fxValidatonNumberMenu` are just for reference. I'd commented it to avoid error codes. You can see a complete implementation on my repository: https://github.com/equiman/hardhatmac/blob/master/tools.sh

Answer (score 3):

you can use this to connect your specific device :

```
   * adb devices
  --------------
    List of devices attached
    9f91cc67    offline
    emulator-5558   device
```

example i want to connect to the first device "9f91cc67"

```
* adb -s 9f91cc67 tcpip 8080
---------------------------
restarting in TCP mode port: 8080
```

then

```
* adb -s 9f91cc67 connect 192.168.1.44:8080
----------------------------------------
connected to 192.168.1.44:8080
```

maybe this help someone

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shell script I made for myself:

```
#! /bin/sh

for device in `adb devices | awk '{print $1}'`; do
  if [ ! "$device" = "" ] && [ ! "$device" = "List" ]
  then
    echo " "
    echo "adb -s $device $@"
    echo "------------------------------------------------------"
    adb -s $device $@
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of convenience, one can create run configurations, which set the `ANDROID_SERIAL`:

[image: screenshot]

Where the `adb_wifi.bat` may look alike (only positional argument `%1%` and `"$1"` may differ):

```
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect %1%:5555
```

The advance is, that `adb` will pick up the current `ANDROID_SERIAL`.
In shell script also `ANDROID_SERIAL=xyz adb shell` should work.

This statement is not necessarily wrong:

```
-s SERIAL  use device with given serial (overrides $ANDROID_SERIAL)
```

But one can as well just change the `ANDROID_SERIAL` right before running the `adb` command.

---

One can even set eg. `ANDROID_SERIAL=192.168.2.60:5555` to define the destination IP for `adb`.
This also permits to run `adb shell`, with the command being passed as "script parameters".

Answer (score 1):

On shells such as `bash` or `zsh` you might get automatic completion for device names after typing `adb -s` + <kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>.

Also see the project page at https://github.com/mbrubeck/android-completion which says:

> On many Linux distributions it is installed and enabled by default. If you don't have it already, you can probably find it in your package repository (e.g. "aptitude install bash-completion").

Device name completion also appears to work on macos, not clear if that was done as part of Android Studio, Android SDK installation or some homebrew package.

Answer (score 1):

Use the device name before the shell command
adb -s 7f1c864e shell