# Running adb commands on all connected devices

Tags: android, adb

Is there a way of running adb commands on all connected devices? To uninstall an app from all connected devices with "adb uninstall com.example.android".

The commands I am interested in is mainly install and uninstall.

I was thinking about writing a bash script for this, but I feel like someone should have done it already :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Create a bash file and name it e.g. `adb+`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
adb devices | while read -r line
do
if [ ! "$line" = "" ] && [ "$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}')" = "device" ]
then
    device=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}')
    echo "$device" "$@" ...
    adb -s "$device" "$@"
fi
done
```

Usage: `./adb+ <command>`

Comment: Works great! Thanks! The only thing missing now is doing it in parallel :)

Comment: `adb -s $device $@ &` will do in parallel

Comment: Should this work for adb shell commands? Works for 'adb+ root', but it seems to direct all commands into the first device shell for 'adb+ shell setenforce 0'

Comment: @Habib It seems the adb shell command will consume stdin, so you can use the shell -n option and the shell command will not consume the rest of stdin. Link to answer:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/44634888/6454399

Answer (score 12):

Building on @Oli's answer, this will also let the command(s) run in parallel, using `xargs`.  Just add this to your `.bashrc` file:

```
function adball()
{
    adb devices | egrep '\t(device|emulator)' | cut -f 1 | xargs -t -J% -n1 -P5 \
          adb -s % "$@"
}
```

and apply it by opening a new shell terminal, `. ~/.bashrc`, or `source ~/.bashrc`.

1. If you only want to run on devices (or only on emulators), you can change the `(device|emulator)` grep by removing the one you don't want.  This command as written above will run on **all** attached devices and emulators.
2. the `-J%` argument specifies that you want xargs to replace the first occurrence of `%` in the utility with the value from the left side of the pipe (stdin). 
   **NOTE**: *this is for BSD (Darwin / Mac OS X) `xargs`.  For GNU/Linux `xargs`, the option is `-I%`*.
3. `-t` will cause xargs to print the command it is about to run immediately before running it.
4. `-n1` means xargs should only use at most `1` argument in each invocation of the command (as opposed to some utilities which *can* take multiple arguments, like `rm` for example).
5. `-P5` allows up to `5` parallel processes to run simultaneously.  If you want instead to run the commands sequentially, simply remove the entire `-P5` argument.  This also allows you to have two variations of the command (`adball` and `adbseq`, for example) -- one that runs in parallel, the other sequentially.

To prove that it is parallel, you can run a shell command that includes a sleep in it, for example:

```
$ adball shell "getprop ro.serialno ; date ; sleep 1 ; date ; getprop ro.serialno"
```

You can use this to run any `adb` command you want (yes, even `adball logcat` will work! but it might look a little strange because both logs will be streaming to your console in parallel, so you won't be able to distinguish which device a given log line is coming from).

---

The benefit of this approach over @dtmilano's `&` approach is that `xargs` will continue to block the shell as long as at least one of the parallel processes is still running:  that means you can break out of both commands by simply using `^C`, just like you're used to doing.  With dtmilano's approach, if you were to run `adb+ logcat`, then both logcat processes would be backgrounded, and so you would have to manually kill the logcat process yourself using `ps` and `kill` or `pkill`.  Using xargs makes it look and feel just like a regular blocking command line, and if you only have one device, then it will work exactly like `adb`.

Comment: Which version of xargs do you use? I don't find any documented version which includes the option -J%. Is there an alternative option? I would like to use adball with xargs on mingw/msys in context of msysgit (xargs GNU findutils version 4.4.2).

Comment: @CarlosSobrinho, thanks for that; tested and it appears you are correct on GNU/Linux.  The `-I%` option is for BSD/Darwin/Mac OS X.  I've edited the answer to clarify and give the GNU version.

Comment: @arne.jans, that^ should answer your question re -J :)

Comment: I've used an alias instead:
`alias adball="adb devices | egrep '\t(device|emulator)' | cut -f 1 | xargs -t -J% -n1 -P5 adb -s % \"\$@\""`

Comment: Love this. Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 6):

This is an improved version of the script from 強大な. The original version was not matching some devices.

```
DEVICES=`adb devices | grep -v devices | grep device | cut -f 1`
for device in $DEVICES; do
    echo "$device $@ ..."
    adb -s $device $@
done
```

Comment: Thanks. Works for me. Only had to change "$ADB" to "adb", as i got error "line 1: devices: command not found".

Comment: Ops, fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To add in the ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc:

> **`alias adb-all="adb devices | awk 'NR>1{print \$1}' | parallel -rkj0 --tagstring 'on {}: ' adb -s {}"`**

Examples:

- `$ adb-all shell date`
- `$ adb-all shell getprop net.hostname`
- `$ adb-all sideload /path/to/rom.zip`
- `$ adb-all install /path/filename.apk`
- `$ adb-all push /usr/local/bin/frida-server-arm64 /data/local/tmp/frida-server`

---

*Explanation: `awk` extracts the device id/host (first column: `print $1`) of every lines except the first one (`NR>1`) to remove the "List of devices attached" header line), then gnu parallel runs `adb -s <HOSTNAME> <whatever-is-passed-to-the-alias>` on whatever non-empty line (`-r`) in the order specified (`-k`, to avoid random order / fastest response order) and prepend each line with `on <DEVICE>:\t` for clarity, all in parallel (`-j0`, possible to set another number to define how many adb should be ran in parallel instead of unlimited).*

:)

Answer (score 4):

This is the highest result on Google, so for all Windows users coming here let me add [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49286080/1955202) by User [zingh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3578279/zingh) (slightly modified to accept arbitrary commands, rather than "only" `install`

Batch file (`adball.bat`):

```
FOR /F "skip=1"  %%x IN ('adb devices') DO start adb -s %%x %*
```

Call as:

```
adball uninstall com.mypackage
```

(`%*` takes all input parameters, my line above makes it so that all commands are passed to adb as they are, so that you can type multiple words, flags etc.)

Note: you can even use this directly from the Android Studio "run all" popup, if you install the `Powershell`-plugin. You can add `adball` to your path, then double-tap `ctrl` and run

```
powershell adball uninstall com.mypackage
```

Comment: My contribution here is quite minor, don't forget to go to the linked post and leave an upvote there as well :)

Comment: Works here (Windows 11). None of the other solutions work

Answer (score 1):

[adb wrapper](https://github.com/zielmicha/adb-wrapper) supports selecting multiple targets for adb commands and parallel execution.

From its README:

```
# Installation
./install.sh ~/apps/android-sdk-linux
# Execute adb commands on all connected devices.
adb set-target all
# Execute adb commands on given devices.
adb set-target emulator-5554 C59KGT14263422
# Use GNU parallel for parallel install.
adb set-parallel true
```

(Disclaimer: I have written half of it)

Comment: Hi, downloaded and installed your tool. Trying to perform "adb set-target all" will issue an error: "adb: usage: unknown command set-target". Couldn't find any documentation in the link you attached.