# Why does ADB commands break a bash script loop?

Tags: bash, adb

I'm noticing a problem when running multiple adb commands from a shell script loop most of the commands does not execute.

**This is an example script.**

Script name: `adbscript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

devicecount=0
while read device; do
    ((devicecount++))
    serialno="NA"
    appinstallcount="NA"
    echo "Processing Device #$devicecount: $device"
    # serialno=$(adb -s $device shell getprop ro.serialno)
    # appinstallcount=$(adb -s $device shell pm list packages | wc -l)
    echo -e "Device: $device | Serialno: $serialno | Apps installed: $appinstallcount\n"
done < <(adb devices | egrep "\bdevice\b" | awk '{print $1}')
echo "Finished."
```

**Output with adb commands commented out**

I have 5 devices connected. When running from the bash file without the**adb** commands this is the output.  It iterates through each of the 5 loops.

```
Processing Device #1: 192.168.15.93:5123
Device: 192.168.15.93:5123 | Serialno: NA | Apps installed: NA

Processing Device #2: 192.168.15.95:5123
Device: 192.168.15.95:5123 | Serialno: NA | Apps installed: NA

Processing Device #3: emulator-5554
Device: emulator-5554 | Serialno: NA | Apps installed: NA

Processing Device #4: 31005c77c8cfb200
Device: 31005c77c8cfb200 | Serialno: NA | Apps installed: NA

Processing Device #5: 98883837594d4f5453
Device: 98883837594d4f5453 | Serialno: NA | Apps installed: NA

Finished.
```

**Output with loop containing `ADB` commands**

When the `adb shell` command is uncommented it only properly iterates lines of the first loop.  This is the output with the `adb` command uncommented:

```
Processing Device #1: 192.168.15.93:5123
Device: 192.168.15.93:5123 | Serialno: 98883837594d4f5453 | Apps installed: 442

Finished.
```

Can someone explain this behavior and what would have to be done to have all the lines and all the loops processed?

By the way, this is the output supplied to the script (one liner command and output):

```
$ adb devices | egrep "\bdevice\b" | awk '{print $1}'
192.168.15.93:5123
192.168.15.95:5123
emulator-5554
31005c77c8cfb200
98883837594d4f5453
```

Comment: Best guess -- the `adb` commands are consuming stdin.  Try redirecting stdin  `</dev/null` in the `adb` commands.

Comment: Thanks!  It works.  If you put your resolution in the form of an answer, I'll accept the answer and upvote the contribution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`adb shell` connects stdin to the command running on the device, which will generally consume stdin until a EOF is reached.  So these commands consume all of the rest of your device names, causing the loop to exit.

Run `adb` with a stdin redirection, so they get an immediate EOF without messing with what you're trying to loop over:

```
serialno=$(adb </dev/null -s $device shell getprop ro.serialno)
appinstallcount=$(adb </dev/null -s $device shell pm list packages | wc -l)
```

Comment: You can also use 'adb shell -n <your commands>' to prevent reading from stdin

Comment: @ldanko write this as an answer, it is really a helpful one.

Answer (score 2):

While @ChrisDodd's root cause analysis is correct and his solution works fine in general, for `adb` automation purposes it is preferable to use `adb exec-out` instead of suggested `adb </dev/null shell` for simple adb shell commands.

Also why use `grep` when you are already using `awk`?

```
for device in $(adb devices | awk '$2=="device"{print$1}')
do
    serialno=$(adb -s $device exec-out getprop ro.serialno)
    appinstallcount=$(adb -s $device exec-out pm list packages | wc -l)
    ...
done
```

For `adb exec-out` to work you need both your host PC and devices have somewhat recent `adb` (or `adbd` in case of devices) version - `platform-tools` v24+ and Android 5.1+ should do.

Comment: I use `adb` for lots of task for communicating with my devices.  I spend 99 percent of my device/computer time using my computer, the large keyboard, and multiple screens.  So the many features of the **adb** command are valuable.  I had been stumped by this (what had been a limitation for me) for a long time.  I have plugged the `adb </dev/null` into all my tools and it works perfectly and resolves all the issues I have been experiencing.  I'll explore what you are suggesting, but at present replacing `</dev/null` with `exec-out` fails in every tested case.

Comment: Thanks! I used **grep** in this case, while quickly taking a sample block from one of my tools that could easily be tested to show a description of my problem and what I was looking for.  I spent a little time in fine tuning it.  I removed a lot of redundancy, but I see, I could have still removed more.  After posting it, I notice there is some cleanup that can be performed, including the redundancy you pointed out.  I don't see some of the variations of expressing making much difference to the actual problem and solution.

Comment: While your answer doesn't address the **input/redirect issue**  of the question, the script example you provided explains merit of the exec-out. Thanks again for the contribution. I'm upvoting your answer as having benefit for using adb in bash scripts.  But if it addressing the error of the question, I'm missing something.

Comment: I do not know how clearer I could possibly be. Unlike `adb shell`  the `adb exec-out` command does not consume `stdin` therefore it solves your original problem.

Comment: Your comment added clarity.  Removing the **shell** argument from the commandline resolved the error I was getting in implementing your version.  It wasn't clear before I commented on the confusion and problem.  I've already expressed appreciation for expanding my knowledge on the tools.  Learning more efficient scripting methods is a good thing.  Thanks for taking the time to add clarification.  By the way, reviewing my bash commands, I hadn't realized the **shell** argument was so prevalent in all my tools.