# Unable to install .apk on device

Tags: android

When I am trying to install the apk I am getting this error.

```
Failed to install Sample.apk on device 'S5570f3a60af0': adb rejected install command with: more than one device
[2014-03-07 15:23:51 - Sample] com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: more than one device
[2014-03-07 15:23:51 - Sample] Launch canceled!
```

I tried restarting the system and device, cleaning the project but still unable to solve this issue. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the current application from your device and then intall .apk file.

Comment: I'd start `adb` manually with command: `adb devices`. see [this SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654718) for example.

Comment: You have too many devices connected to your machine. You should target only one machine.

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens when you move from one computer to another computer and you try to install same application from different computer.

Since the application is already there in the device, hence older version of eclipse is not allowing you to directly install the application file.

If you have Eclipse Juno version then it directly allows to install the application even if you have previous version of your application in the device.

For right you can solve this error by manually removing application from the device and then re-run the project.

Comment: I haven't changed my computer nor my device. and I have also uninstalled the previous program from my device still was of no use.

Comment: The un-plug the device and re-plug and the try again.

Comment: did.. still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Because you are probably using another computer for deployment, you should try removing the application via the settings menu on the physical device (or the emulator).

**Edit:** In the log, you can see that ADB throws you the error that there are more then *one* devices attached. Try to see if you can resolve that problem be removing usb cables.

Comment: I am using the same computer :( didn't change anything

Comment: You may still try uninstalling it from the device, did that work for you?

Comment: Did you see my edit above? Try removing usb cables, so only one device is attached. Then try again.

Comment: yes, I tried removing usb cables, changing cables, etc but it isnt working

Comment: Make a virtual device, and see if you can deploy it to there. If it works, there is probably a problem with your cable/phone/adb driver

Answer (score 0):

I've seen corrupted .apks that won't load on a device, with weird IOExceptions. Following these steps in Eclipse seems to prevent the problems I've seen:

Make sure that Project -> Build Automatically is turned off (that is, unchecked)
Project -> Clean..., select "Clean All Projects", make sure the "Start a Build Automatically" checkbox is unchecked, and click OK.
Use File -> Export -> Android -> Export Android Application to create the APK.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you have more than one device connected in the same network or it is open.Use the following commands

First check the devices that are attached by using the below command

```
$ adb devices
```

This lists the number of devices attached will be shown like this

```
017296d5904c device
192.168.56.101:5555 device
```

Suppose 017296d5904c is your device then run this command in cmd

```
$ adb -s 017296d5904c shell pm list packages
```

-s: to make command to specific device

For example check this out 
http://codetheory.in/execute-adb-commands-query-particular-android-device-emulator/