# Detecting if emulator has started completely

Tags: android, adb

I want to check if all the emulators has booted successfully. I have tried with this command `adb shell getprop sys.boot_completed` this works if i am running one emulator. But if i have more than one emulator this command returns error as following: `error: more than one device/emulator`.How to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use ADB Shell when Multiple Devices are connected? Fails with "error: more than one device and emulator"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654718/how-to-use-adb-shell-when-multiple-devices-are-connected-fails-with-error-mor)

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the device serial number on the `adb` command line to let it know which one you want to interact with.

Something like

```
adb -s emulator-5554 shell ...
```

Also, if you are doing it from the command line, multiple times and you are starting to be annoyed by that, you can try https://gist.github.com/dtmilano/4537110 which allows you to select the device

```
$ adb shell
1) 02783201431feeee device           3) emulator-5554
2) 3832380FA5F30000 device           4) emulator-5556
Select the device to use, <Q> to quit: 1
$
```

Comment: Diego, if that's your understanding of the OP's question, then why did not you just mark it as duplicate?