# Is it possible to connect two devices with USB and run adb commands on one

Tags: android, adb

I want to connect Phones(both android) : Phone A to Phone B, where Phone B connect phone A as a adb debugging device (using Android Terminal app ) and run ADB commands on phone A

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use ADB Shell when Multiple Devices are connected? Fails with "error: more than one device and emulator"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654718/how-to-use-adb-shell-when-multiple-devices-are-connected-fails-with-error-mor)

Answer (score 1):

yes you can connect 2 Devices using 2 different USB cables , or emulator if your testing on it 
when you do adb devices you should see 2 devices connected info 
use adb  -s [device id] for normal devices ] shell
use adb -e [device id] for emulator  shell

Answer (score 0):

you can use a router to connect wireless debugging two android phones.
turn on wireless debugging in A phone.
use Android terminal app on B phone and run below command on it.
adb tcpip [a phone debugging port]
adb connect [a phone ip]
then run adb devices

but stil i dont know about this using cables.