# How do I run app on selected android device?

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

I have two emulators and one physical device connected. When I run `adb devices` it is showing three devices.
Now I am running reactive native app using `npx react-native run-android` and it runs app on all devices.

I want to run it on selected devices only. I have a need to compare two versions parallel which I will run on physical and emulator.
I am using VSCode.

Can someone, tell me a way to run react native app only on selected android device?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654718/how-to-use-adb-shell-when-multiple-devices-are-connected-fails-with-error-mor

Comment: Yes, this helps. Not exact, but can be used as work around. After generating apk we can run on specific target

Comment: But this does not help on checking app output for runtime changes, which is main advantage of react-native