# Multiple devices issue in tcpip

Tags: android, terminal, tcp

I'm using termux in Android
I connect my using tcpip
I can't excute command  reason show multiple devices connected
adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device

Comment: you can specify a device to connect to like in  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14655015/16050098)

Comment: if it is an emulator, you have to use IP and port instead of the device name. e.g. `adb -s 192.168.20.10:5555 shell`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

adb allows multiple devices to be connected which will not allow to run the shell
[image: adb shell on multiple connected devices not allowed]

you can try restarting the server using the following command and try again

> adb kill-server
>
> adb start-server

it worked for me some one already mentioned about the -s Serial number ( phone / emulator id )

> adb -s SERIAL shell

so that will also be a good option to try

you can also try command line to connect with the target using

> adb connect xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port

you may also try

> adb disconnect

and retry

Good luck