# Granting GSAM battery permission via ADB (issue, Help) ADB finding 2 devices

Tags: adb

So I am trying to grant access to GSAM battery via ADB but I keep getting a message saying "More than One device/emulator" I believe the one with the numbers is my phone and the emulator I don't know what it is.

What should I do at this point? If Possible if I can get a written answer where I could copy and paste into ADB?

First post here. Hoping to be a frequent member[Picture of the Problem in ADB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWki4.png).

Thank you!

Comment: Please do not post terminal commands and output as screen shot. Just copy and paste the text content into your question and format it as code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/14654718/150978