# How to connect to a http server running in android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a HTTP server working on my android emulator listening to port 8080. How can I connect to it from same PC's browser? I tried 127.0.0.1 but it couldn't connect.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720346/how-to-get-the-android-emulators-ip-address

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to enable port forwarding in `adb`. For example:

```
adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080
```

This will forward incoming connections to *localhost* TCP/8080 to the emulator TCP/8080.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)'s the reference.

Comment: The note about localhost is useful. To be super clear, after forwarding, you can browse to `http://127.0.0.1:8080` on your PC and you will see whatever is being served up via port 8080 on the emulator (in my case I was listening to HTTP requests and serving up HTML which showed up on my laptop just as expected - super cool and super useful!).