# Connect Android Device (PhoneGap) in Eclipse to 127.0.0.1

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, wamp

I'm using Eclipse with PhoneGap to develop an app. For the run config, I'm using Android Device because it is faster compared to using AVD.

So, what I wanna do is to upload a file from the phone (USB connected to eclipse via laptop) to my localhost server. Mainly speaking, to upload a file to a remote server. But as for the initial part, I just want to upload it to the localhost.

**(index.html)**
Here is my upload script from HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Capture Photo</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var pictureSource;   // picture source
    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    }

    function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
      var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

      smallImage.style.display = 'block';

      smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

      var options = new FileUploadOptions();
      options.fileKey="file";
      options.fileName=imageData.substr(imageData.lastIndexOf('/')+1);      
      options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
      console.log("Filename: " + options.fileName);
      var params = new Object();
      params.value1 = "test";
      params.value2 = "param";
      options.params = params;
      options.chunkedMode = false;
      var ft = new FileTransfer();
      ft.upload(imageData, "http://127.0.0.1:80/upload_file.php", win, fail, options);
    }

    function capturePhoto() {
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail,
        { 
          quality: 50,
          sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
          destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL
        }
      );
    }

    function win(r) {
      console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
      console.log("Response = " + r.response);
      console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
      alert(r.response);
    }

    function fail(error) {
      alert("An error has occurred: Code = " = error.code);
    }

    function onFail(message) {
      alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
    <img style="display:none;width:300px" id="smallImage" src="" />
    <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />

  </body>
</html>
```

And yes, what the code does is it captures a photo with camera and that photo will be uploaded to the server. But my main thing to be focused here is to upload it.

**(c:/wamp/www/upload.php)**
Here is the php script for the server-side:

```
 <?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
  echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "";
} else {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb";
  echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "";
  if (file_exists("D:/PHPUPLOAD/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  } else {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "C:/PHPUPLOAD/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]); //Save location
    echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
}
?>
```

It should be okay right if I'm using Android Device instead of AVD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found a way to work it out. I forgot to mention that my device and laptop is within the same network (wifi), so in order to make it connect to the laptop's localhost, I need to find its local IP address.

In `cmd` type `ipconfig` and find the host's IPv4 address. For example:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f0b2:6e7f:53fb:24e8%13
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.3
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

In my case, it is `192.168.1.3`.

To make it visible, you need to allow Apache server to accept all incoming requests. To do so, open up Apache's `httpd.conf` file and modify the following:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Test the IP address in your phone. You should see WAMP homepage.

Use this line in `index.html` to connect to your localhost

```
ft.upload(imageData, "http://192.168.1.3/upload_file.php", win, fail, options);
```

And for the `upload_file.php`:

```
<?php
    print_r($_FILES);
    $new_image_name = "namethisimage.jpg";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $new_image_name);

    echo "<img width='500px' src='namethisimage.jpg'>";
?>
```

Thank you guys for the response :)

Comment: hi this is currect code for me what are the code in android code.?multipart image upload on local host

Answer (score 1):

You can use 127.0.0.1 to reach the emulator's host, if you are in the same machine. If you want to reach the development machine, you can use 10.0.2.2.

Refer to [How to get the Android Emulator's IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720346/how-to-get-the-android-emulators-ip-address)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Usb connectivity does not provide network access to the mobile device .

For connecting to localhost see this:

[How can I access my localhost from my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device)

If you wish to run the same code on a remote server then phonegap has the option of Domain White listing.

you can get more info on that here :

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide