# Android emulator: How to connect to local network?

Tags: android

I've got a client on my phone running. Now I got a server app on the emulator running. My phone is connected via wifi to the network. When I open my app on the emulator my app shows that the ip is 0.0.0.0? How can I connect to the emulator via my wifi network? Or do I need 2 phones to test this?

My emulator does have a external ip? Do I need to portforward and connect via the external ip?

Answer (score 0):

here 2 solutions for this problem. 
1. That I like - use GenyMotion project http://www.genymotion.com/ - it will create virtul box on the local machine and you can locate it with ifconfig command for linux and ipconfig for windows

2. Try to connect with ADB and find out ip address for your emulator, also look here [How to get the Android Emulator's IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720346/how-to-get-the-android-emulators-ip-address)

Answer (score 0):

I used genymotion with ADB.

The adb.exe is located in the platform-tools folder of the Android SDK. Just open cmd en go to the location and type:

```
adb shell
ifconfig eth0
```

then you get the correct emulator IP.