# Connect from machine on local network TO an Android emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I've seen a lot of questions about how to connect from an Android Emulator, but few about how to connect TO it.

I'm using the emulator that comes with eclipse for android to run a server on an android emulator, I would like like to connect TO this server from another machine located on my local network. The computer hosting the emulator is connected to that local network.

I read things about forwarding ports from the host computer to the emulator, but it was unclear.

Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720346/how-to-get-the-android-emulators-ip-address) is a post were says which is the android emulator ip address. You can communicate between app and server (server and app) with web services.

Comment: Thanks. I already read that answer but i think i misunderstood it. Does the answer say that the ip address of the android emulator is the same ip address as the machine hosting the emulator ?