# Use android emulator on the same subnet as the pc

Tags: android, android-studio, networking, android-emulator

I´m using Android Studio with Android emulators. The problem is that the emulator have an ip address in a another subnet, so the pc and the proxy server are unreachable because security rules of the company where I work prevent it.

I need internet connection in the emulator to test the app so, Can I assign to the emulator a ip address in the same subnet that pc to have access to the proxy and then have internet access?

Thanks

EDIT:
I can do it using Genymotion, setting network brigge mode instead NAT mode, but I dont know how to do it with Android AVD and Android Studio.´
I tried setting static IP using ifconfig, but it didn´t work because DHCP Server must be who assign IP address.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1722427/4350275

Comment: Same problem, Android emulators is not the best option for corporate proxy