# Can't call a Web Service from Android but It work from UWP

Tags: android, web-services, wcf, xamarin

I have to implement a Web Service in a Xamarin Project. 
So I create a simple Web Service to do some test. There is the code I used to :

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:62056/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("DataTransferTest.svc/HelloWorld").Result;
                string json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;    
}
```

I already try to change the `http://localhost:62056/` to `http:10.0.0.2:62056` but nothing change.

I already configure my ISS express like this :

```
<site name="LogiStock.WebServices2" id="4">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\TeamExplorer\LogiStock-1.0.1\LogiStock.WebServices2" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:62056:localhost" />
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:62056:192.168.90.139" />
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:62056:127.0.0.1" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
```

There is the error I got when i'm trying this code :

> One or more errors occured. An error occured while sending the request
>   _Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused) _Connection refused

I really hope that someone can help me, I really don't know what is wrong..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1722427/4984832

Comment: do you miss the "//" of your url `http:10.0.0.2:62056` ?

Comment: No, I put them into my URL

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, you have the following line in your manifest file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```